# What should I do to open Postgresql for remote usage

Tags: postgresql

I have a windows server VPS and currently there is a Postgres database running on it and wanted to open port 5432 in firewall to enable remote usage of Postgres but I wanted to know if there is other security options I should enable to prevent hacking?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make a good password which is not reused anywhere, and verify that the system demands use of the password. If your adversaries are script kiddies wanting to use your CPU to mine cryptocurrency, this is entirely sufficient. If you think the 3-letter agencies are after you, you might want to take additional steps, or give up.

No one is ever going to guess AJ8h4eos against an online system, and certainly not F6evVFHaXakzkKDCjLQzSla9n.  Well, not until reading this post, anyway.

Comment: I have already got ransomware attack

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh  There is nothing we can do with that info.  Did you have a good password?  Was it configured to demand that password?  Did they even get in through PostgreSQL in the first place?

Comment: In addition, don't ever have an application connect with a superuser.

Comment: yes the password was `AvFpQiGlra&o!6$NK6A7s8p` I think its strong enough. Yea they have connected through Postgres

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to open Postgresql for remote usage?...but I wanted to know if there is other security options I should enable to prevent hacking?

Don't directly open your database / server to remote usage. Rather create an API, that's accessible remotely, to be the middleman to access your database in a controlled way. That is the best practice way.

Comment: I want to connect with pgadmin remotely, is it possible with API?

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh Why? Like you mentioned in the other comment about being randsomwared, exposing your database to the internet increases this risk. Losing your data from being encrypted by randsomware sucks. An API getting encrypted is easy to fix by just re-deploying it. An API will allow you to interface with your database and run queries but only what you explicitly expose as endpoints in your API.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this without exposing postgres to the rest of the internet, there are basically three options.

SSH tunnelling

IP firewall (and/or pg_hba.conf)

VPN